# Genetic Algorithm for Hybrid Flowshops Scheduling using Python

Tags: python, optimization, genetic-algorithm, cplex, genetic

I apply optimization tool to solve pratical **production planning** problem.

My current problem is doing planning for a factory with various items in a unique production flow stage. In each stage, there are few parallel machines as graph below.

[image]

I have done maths MILP model, and try to solve by CPLEX but it too hard to handle the big scale model by itself.

Currently, I prepare to use Genetic Algorithm to solve it, but don't know where to start.

I have some knowdlege in Python Language. My friends, please advise how I start to deal with this problem?

Do someone have a similar solved problem with code, that I can have a reference?

Comment: Hi, have you had a look at the examples at https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/Decision-Optimization-with-CPO-samples ?

Comment: Hi Alex, Can you send the Cplex code for it?

For your concerns, my problem is hybrid flowshops, that is combining of parallel machines in each stages, and product go throw 1 sequence only, not job shop scheduling. Do you have the example for it?

Comment: Hi, in CPLEX_Studio128\python\examples\cp\visu you may find a few flowshop examples

Comment: Hi Alex, Do you have lot streamming example? cause the axamples comply that the job have only 1 lot, and have to finish all before moving to other stage. That increase huge leadtime when I deal to mass production plan.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start writing code(or using someone else's) you must understand the theory behind the scene.
What are the main entities of your Production System?

You need to formulate optimization objectives,optimal schedule but defined in terms of optimization problem.

One example that comes to my mind
[https://github.com/jpuigcerver/jsp-ga](http://jsp-ga)

Take a look at this thesis
[http://lancet.mit.edu/~mbwall/phd/thesis/thesis.pdf](http://A%20Genetic%20Algorithm%20for%20Resource-Constrained%20Scheduling)

Comment: Thank you for your advise, Richard.
I actually built the maths model and Cplex tool, please have a look at this draft:
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19faqx4gPhw2SOCPenCGgH_EhNPpQgOWM)
My problem now is how to convert Maths Model to Python Language.